# Does it make sense to create a docker image from scratch for an application?

Tags: c++, docker

I have some questions about docker:

- Does it make sense to create docker images from scratch?
  Let me explain: I saw in a post a method to create the smallest docker go image (https://medium.com/@chemidy/create-the-smallest-and-secured-golang-docker-image-based-on-scratch-4752223b7324). I was thinking about making the same for a C/C++ application by using full static compilation, but when I take a look on dockerhub I don't see any scratch based images expect alpine, centos, debian... So I was wondering if there is a objection to do so.
- The other question is about docker isolation based on cgroups, etc and libraries. Does the OS still optimize dynamic library load?

Comment: If all the images are not much appreciated to you. You can create docker images from scratch just for yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It definitely does make sense to use scratch-based containers.  If you can fully statically compile your complete app and have no need for a shell then do it.  Smaller, faster and more secure is definitely a good thing - I tend to write everything in go these days but it should be possible in C/C++ too.

Not sure what your second question means, but maybe you're asking whether there will be only one copy of a shared library in host memory if that library is used in multiple containers?  TBH, I'm not sure, but my guess would be that there would be more than one copy in memory, since (if no other reason) it's probably hard for the host to know that it's really the same file.

Comment: Thanks for the first question it answers my concerns.

As for the second one what I really don't know is if loading libraries is optimized between containers. Let say ContainerA load libFoo, does this load is optimized if containerB running on the same host needs that same libFoo. And of course libFoo is a shared layer between containerA and containerB.